# Using Polygon to raster (folder)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5, rasterization

I'm having a problem when trying to convert "Polygon to Raster (folder)" on ArcGIS 10.5 ( SDM Toolbox v2.3).

Why are all output rasters much smaller than the input polygon?

Comment: Fix extent in environment settings.

Comment: What are the precise steps that you perform when seeing this from starting ArcMap with a Blank Map?